# Indexing an HTML page that redirects onload

Tags: gwt, search, seo, indexing

I have a pure GWT based website and as we are aware the search engines cannot index pure gwt based websites. Thus, I have created an alternate web page as shown below which is stored as a separate html in the war folder. The purpose of this webpage is to enlist and index details regarding my website. This page is never displayed on my website, but instead is meant only for indexing. The url leading to this web page is part of the Sitemaps.xml. Thus I am assuming that the below html will be indexed because it's a part of Sitemaps. So here are my questions:

1. Will the content I give in the div with id "crawler" be indexed given the fact that it is scheduled for removal onload and that the browser is redirected to another url on load?
2. Is there a better way to get the content indexed for a pure GWT website which does not have any html based user interface?
3. I can also have urls that will invoke a servlet and return a response that is meant for indexing. But then the same url will be displayed in search results, which is not useful. In other words, I am trying to figure out a way in which the content gets indexed, but when the user clicks the search result he should be redirected to the home page instead of showing the indexed content.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function load(){
            element = document.getElementById("crawler");
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            window.location.href='http://<mysite>.com';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad='load()'>
    <div id="crawler">
                  <CONTENT TO BE INDEXED>......
            </div>
    </body>
```

As you can see here the div (crawler) that contains all the content that is meant for indexing, is removed as soon as the body loads. Apart from this the page also redirects to the home page of the site on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crawler will read in the entire contents of the page for indexing, so it will have no trouble picking up the portion within the div. The onload is not executed by the crawler prior to reading the page.

A method I have used in the past was to generate static html versions of the pages and reference these through the sitemap.xml.  Users landing on the html page would then be directed to the equivalent dynamic page when they click on a link (ie: Buy or Specifications).  This worked well for search engine placement with many pages appearing in the top ten.

Comment: This seems a reasonable option. Just that in my case the page to be indexed is never to be shown to the user. Hence having a link that required user to take action, for achieving redirection, won't suffice here. Consecutively, I added the onload handler that removes the div and also redirects where I wish. But still I am not sure if this a legitimate practice or is it frowned upon.

Comment: Search engines take a dim view to redirecting users to a different site or base URL.  This practice is specifically forbidden by Google for example.  However redirecting users to another page within the same site should not pose a problem.  Google's Webmaster Guidelines addresses this issue: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2721217

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to notify the search engines about an undiscoverable website's content is to create a HTML website (as you did). If you create redirects based on the crawler, search engines will not love you. I think you have to fill out your HTML with content with relevant information and add

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://gwtsite.com/exact_url"/>`

tag to your website's head section. This will notify the search engines that the other site has to appear in the SERP-s instead of the HTML one.

Comment: A search result would show a title (link) and some summary. By giving the canonical address, will the title point to canonical address and will still contain the summary generated from the static page? In my case I want all the static html pages that are meant to be indexed, to finally go to the home page from the SERP.

Comment: To add to what I asked in the above comment, please take a look at the following FAQ answer snippet:<BR/>Must the content on a set of pages be similar to the content on the canonical version?

Yes. The rel="canonical" attribute should be used only to specify the preferred version of many pages with identical content (although minor differences, such as sort order, are okay).<BR/>[link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)<BR/>Given this, I seem to have a problem. My static pages are not at all similar to the content of the home page.

Comment: If you redirect visitors on every indexed sites search engines will ban you. I am sure. If you have not the similar content on html and gwt, why are you redirect visitors there? If search engines can not read your gwt you can point to them with a canonical...